# Android Navigation Component: How can I always run an app from start destination?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have start authorization screen, I want the user to log in every time the application starts, even onResume

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you're exactly trying to achieve? The question is not clear enough.

Comment: @ManuRamV in my app I have an authorization screen as start destination, I need to clear the navigation stack every time user close the application, even if the user just minimized the application, so every time user opens app he logged in on the first screen, like in bank apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onResume() of your `Activity` navigate to your authorization screen. We want to use a kind of navigation that can be used from any fragment, so the best option would be the navigate(deepLink) method.

1. Add a DeepLink to the AuthorizationFragment in your `navigation.xml`:

   ```
   <deepLink
   android:id="@+id/deepLink"
   app:uri="http://www.example.com/authorization" />
   ```
2. In `Activity` onResume()

   ```
   findNavController(R.id.container).navigate("http://www.example.com/authorization")
   ```

If the destination is reachable from current NavGraph, it will navigate there.

3. Dismiss the authorization screen simply by calling NavController.navigateUp() from the authorization screen.

See documentation:

[Navigate to a destination with Navigation Component using URI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#uri)

[How to create an implicit deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit)

Comment: Your answer led me to use global action instead, so thank you